# Limited task manager?

Tags: windows, process, task-manager

I know it seems counter-productive, but I was looking for a task manager that it's more limited than the one that comes with Window.

The reason is that some servers that I use (but not manage) have disable the Task Manager. I also have to support users who use these servers.

I can relate to that, since the simple user can do more than he's supposed to do. He could kill process that he's not supposed to kill, for example. But this also has its problems since it's not easy to kill unresponsive user process. I've had Word crashing a couple of times. And there's no easy way to kill.

So, the question is: is there a task manager that only lists the user's process and has the option to only kill (some) processes? Limited to process only started by the user (and not background processes like AV)? And removing the "New Task"?

If not, how hard it'd be to develop in C#? How can you be sure that the "Process is not responding"? I could try to develop but I really doubt they would let something like that developed by me run on their system.

Thank you!

Comment: I doubt that a user can kill processes create by another user, unless the killing user is an administrator. I guess your IT does not want Task Manager because a user might kill (background) processes that run under his account but are needed.

Comment: check if they left you the tasklist and taskkill commands. those can also be used remotely, if you have the necessary privileges.

Comment: @WernerHenze I was thinking about background processes, not processes started by other users.

Comment: @TheUser1024 I'd rather have something easier, so the user itself could use. And, unfortunately, I'm not an admin on the machines.

Comment: I understand the problem you want to solve, but your approach has some very weak points. So weak that my answer to such a request from my users would mainly be laughter and "Funny idea, No!". And please, this is not meant to offend, just to give you an idea. A user for whom Task Manager is too complex, shall not kill processes.

Comment: Maybe this is worth a read: http://lifehacker.com/5232692/kill-frozen-windows-apps-easily

Comment: @TheUser1024 The user doesn't complain / think the Task Manager is too complex: they don't have one. The servers are not mine (I just have users using it) and the server admins decided not to make the Task Manager available: "The user can kill (background) processes that he was not supposed to kill" they say. I'm just trying to fill a middle ground. The lifehacker article seems promising, though!